# xhttp.open() onreadystatechange not firing without an alert after send()

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to get a json string from my server and parse it. Everything is working except my onreadystatechange only triggers if I put an alert after the .send() method. Without the alert the server doesn't always get a "GET" request. The only way I found to fix the problem is to turn the async to false on the open(). I'd prefer if the code was written async.

```
function collectData(){
    var user = document.forms["search"]["user"].value;
    if (user !== ""){
        var url = 'http://localhost:3000/users/'.concat('', user);
        var xhttp;
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest){// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        else{// code for IE6, IE5
            xhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && (this.status == 200 || this.status == 304)) {
                var response = JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText);
                alert(response.data[0].id);
            }
        };
        xhttp.open("GET", url, true);
        xhttp.send();
        alert(url);
    } else {
        alert("Name must be filled out");
        return false;
    }
}
```

I just want to be able to alert for response.data[0].id

edit: adding more code to recreate scenario.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/script.js"></script>
    <title>Exsisting Customer</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form name="search" onsubmit="return collectData()">
        Search customer:<br>
        <input type="text" name="user"><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Odds are that the browser is leaving the page before the script fires. Impossible to tell without a [mcve]

Comment: Try to log in the console the responseText that gives you, maybe is a bad formatted JSON (`console.log(xhttp.responseText);`).

Comment: I added the html where I call the function. 
Also the json is fine. if I get into the onreadystatechange the function works as expected!

Answer (score 0):

You are submitting the form, so the browser starts navigating to a new page as soon as the `onsubmit` function is completed. This may cancel the Ajax request entirely, but if it doesn't, it certainly destroys the JavaScript environment that is waiting for the response.

You need to stay on the same page to process the response with JS.

With the approach you are currently taking, you should `return false` from `collectData`. You should consider moving to modern JS and use `addEventListener` and `event.preventDefault`.

Comment: if I return false how can I navigate to the next page I want to land on?

Comment: Also if you could help me on how to add an event listener that would be really amazing! I am pretty new to JS and all I know is from the internet from different sources. My knowledge has very big gaps!

Comment: Don't mix Ajax and navigating to a new page. If you're going to a new page, then do the work as part of generating the new page on the server.

Comment: I wanted to use AJAX to reload only part of the page. It's filling out a form to store in a database and I just wanted to only replace the forms and not the whole page. I'm not sure that it's AJAX but from my google-ing I thought it was.

Comment: If you want to use Ajax to reload part of the page, then don't let the form submit and navigate to a completely new page.